# Swift File is not fully reconized in the Source Playground Folder (method are missing)

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I created a playground, in this playground, I created a class, I instantiate it, everything worksis fine. So, I create the same class in a source swift file, make my class public but ... I do not have the foundation framework methods! for example, no ... uppercased! While I have these methods in the basic playground (I also use the framework foundation). What am I doing wrong? thanks a lot for your help

/ Works with the Playground /
/ --------------------------/
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

class Person {

```
var firstName: String
var lastName: String

init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName

}

func mergeUpperCase() -> String {
    return firstName.uppercased() + " " + lastName.uppercased()

}
```

}

/ Don't work with the Swift File under Sources /
/ ---------------------------------------------/

import Foundation

public class Person {
    public var firstName: String
    public var lastName: String

```
public init(firName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.firstName = firName
    self.lastName = lastName

}

public func merge() -> String {
    return firstName + " " + lastName

}

public func mergeUpperCase() -> String {
    return firstName.**xxxx** + " " + lastName.**xxxx** // xxxx = no method!
}
```

}

Comment: Does it say "Can't find module Foundation"?

Comment: Hi Sweeper, No ..., there are no error messages. Only, there is no method available after the "." As if he did not recognize the function "import". I tried to recreate a new file "Swift", to create this file separately then to import it ... nothing ... strange